# Should I use relative or absolute urls when pointing to internal pages

Tags: permalinks, pages

This is a simple question, that's probably been asked before. For internal links between pages, is it better to use a relative link or full permalink?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you're talking about.  If you're talking about using just

`<a href="/page-title">Page Title</a>`, then no.  It's better to use the full link.

However, instead of using `http://www.domain.com/page-title`, it's better to use

`<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/page-title`.

The reason you don't want to use relative links is the way wordpress permalinks work.  If you're on a sub-page (`domain.com/about/john`) and you use a relative link to another subpage (`href="/jane"`), it will point to the root URL (`domain.com/jane` instead of `domain/about/jane`.

**UPDATE**

The full `<a>` will be

`<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/page-title">Page Title</a>`

Comment: Hi Josh, Thank you very much for your explanation. Just to clarify, the best way is to do it like so: <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('home'); ?>/page-title</a> ? Did I understand correctly? What if the structure of my site is: http://www.domain.com/subpage/subpage/page-title. Would bloginfo('home') find a page that is down the hierarchy? Thank you!

Comment: Laxmidi, check my update.  You want to have /page-title after the `<?php ?>` tag, but before the end of the `href=""` attribute.

Comment: `bloginfo('home')` gets the domain entered in `Settings -> General -> Wordpress address (URL)`

Comment: `bloginfo( 'home' )` is deprecated use `bloginfo( 'url' )` instead.  See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) for proper usage of `bloginfo()`

Comment: @Chris_O updated answer to show 'url' instead of 'home'.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Josh Allen, Awesome. Thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: @Chris_O, Hi Chris, Thanks for the help. I'll be sure to use 'url'.

Comment: Actually, no. You could use a base href to resolve the relative links to absolute. Relative paths should work perfectly under that setup.