# Relative v.s. absolute URLs: which ones should I use for cross-domain portability?

Tags: permalinks, urls

My question is related to but different [from this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24476/should-i-use-relative-or-absolute-urls-when-pointing-to-internal-pages)

I need to make sure that my URLs work across domains like `staging.domain.com`, `localhost:8000` and `www.domain.com`.

I have local, staging and production environments. I thought relative URLs would be the solution to my problem since I will be using WP Migrate Pro to move data from local to staging to production.

But after reading [this article](http://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/) by Yoast, I am kind of worried. He speaks about SEO problems.

So what type of permalinks should I use? Absolute or Relative? *Or* should I use relative URLs with canonical meta tags on my page templates?

Comment: You'll run into less issues using absolute urls with WordPress and going through the pain of running a search and replace on each deployment step, or, writing scripts to do so.

Comment: I don't see how it's different from the other question you linked. use the API to output absolute URLs.